# How do I beat level 7 hard on Lineum

Tags: lineum

How do I beat level 7 hard mode on Lineum on ABCya? I have tried to use the help piece and the stone pieces but I still cannot figure it out

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The specific problem is definitely clear, no reason to flag this question as unclear